# why i am getting these errors in cloud programming?

Tags: netbeans-7

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: simulation.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at org.cloudbus.cloudsim.ex.mapreduce.Configuration.loadPropertiesFromFile(Configuration.java:35)
```

Comment: It looks like it cannot find your project's configuration file.

Comment: This could be a clue: _The system cannot find the file specified_

Comment: error itself giving u the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Configuration.java file you must have a code to retrieve Properties From a File. There can be two problems

1. Either configuration file is missing
2. If you have configured a path any where in the project that path is invalid after you deploy from local host to cloud